# locally developed react component imported causes error on build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have written a react component locally and installed it in a `create-react-app` project by doing `npm i --save ../path/to/prj` when I am developing everything runs perfectly smooth and fine.

When I build the project, serve it and then point my browser to it, I get this error which I cannot find ANYWHERE by googling which is scary...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStackAddendumByID' of undefined
    at index.js:38299
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:50564)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:50569)
    at t (index.js:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:33018)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:33021)
    at t (index.js:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:32538)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:32975)
    at t (index.js:21)
```

I have verified that when I take out my imported component and rebuild the project, everything serves up just fine, but when the import is there, it throws this error. I have been searching high and low with nothing but dead ends.... any ideas?

Comment: Have you bundled React with the component? If you did, you should define it as [an external](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/), so it uses the one in your actual app. It looks like you are using two different versions of React. React 16 got a new architecture and `getStackAddendumByID` is part of the old one, which has been removed entirely.

Comment: ill have to check later but almost certain they are both 16. component is bundled...ill let you know if it works

Comment: you got me going in the right direction...it was a dependency of my imported component which was using react 15 so it was rather hidden.

Comment: Running into the exact same problem here after upgrading to React 16. Can you provide some more details on how you fixed this?

Comment: somewhere in the dependency tree you have different versions of react. it could be a dependency of imports. If you downgrade your project to react 15 and it works then you will have to chase down where the dependency is